# Разбивка файла на блоки при помощью FileStream (.NET 3.5)

Tags: c#, filestream

Нигде не могу найти правильного подхода:

Есть FileStream для чтения произвольного файла (формат не важен).Он читает из файла блоки некоторого размера.

```
   string fileIn = "C:/data.000";
   string fileOut = "C:/data.rar.gz";

   byte[] buffer = new byte[10240000];

   using (FileStream fstream = File.OpenRead(fileIn))
   {
       while(fstream.Position < fstream.Length)
        {
           fstream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
   }
```

typeOf показывает что "fstream.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length) возвращает System.int32 и равен 10240000, т.е. то значение, которое я задал в качестве размера буфера.

Каким образом получить объект типа(кусок файла), а не размер буфера?

UPD^^ пробую сделать вот так:

```
 private void Compress(string fileInput, string FileOut, Program.StopTrigger abortCheck)
        {
            using (Stream fs = new FileStream(fileInput,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read,10240000,true))
            using (Stream fd = new FileStream(FileOut,FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.Write,10240000,true))
            {
                long dataPortionSize = fs.Length / 64;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[dataPortionSize];
                int nRead;
                for(int i =1; i == 64; i++)
                {
                    Thread th = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        fs.Position = dataPortionSize*i-dataPortionSize;
                        using (GZipStream csStream = new GZipStream(fd, CompressionMode.Compress))
                        {
                            while ((nRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                csStream.Write(buffer, 0, nRead);
                            }
                        } 
                    });
                    th.Start();
                } 
            }
}
```

Файл делится, считывается очень быстро, но никакого сжатия не происходит, записывать соответственно нечего.

Подскажите кто сталкивался с этим

Answer (score 2):

Данные, считанные из файла, находятся в `buffer` по расположению от 0 (второй аргумент вызова `fstream.Read` до `0 + k`, где `k` — число, возвращаемое вызовом `fstream.Read` (вы его не присваиваете никакой переменной, и оно тем самым теряется).

Обратите внимание, что вы при этом получаете просто набор байт. Интерпретация его как объекта какого-либо *типа* лежит на вас (и обычно производится при с использованием методов *десериализации*).

Comment: Почему-то найденные мной примеры десериализации работают по принципу взять объект какого-либо конкретного класса и присвоить данные из файла этому объекту. Это не подходит. Мне явно не хватает мозгов чтобы понять как это сделать.

Comment: @Garrus_En: А этот пример вы видели: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb552731(v=vs.120).aspx?

Comment: посмотрел, но там десериализация XML, немного не понял, почему вы отправили меня по этой ссылке. Дополнил вопрос, похоже я не могу правильно сформулировать вопрос, потому как абсолютно не могу понять как работает FileStream.

Comment: @Garrus_En: Ну, если вам нужна десериализация, то пример XML-десериализации не присваивает данные объекту, а конструирует их при помощи методов десериализатора.